# GitGutter doesn't work

Tags: vim

I've tried to use [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) but it doesn't work and I even don't know where to find a root of error.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
$ vim --version | head -1
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep 12 2013 14:04:26)
$ ll ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
-rw-r--r--  1 coder  staff    12K  8 Dec 23:32 /Users/coder/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
$ ll ~/.vim/bundle/vim-gitgutter
total 56
-rw-r--r--   1 coder  staff    12K  8 Dec 23:17 README.mkd
drwxr-xr-x   4 coder  staff   136B  8 Dec 23:17 autoload
drwxr-xr-x   3 coder  staff   102B  8 Dec 23:17 doc
drwxr-xr-x   3 coder  staff   102B  8 Dec 23:17 plugin
-rw-r--r--   1 coder  staff    16K  8 Dec 23:17 screenshot.png
drwxr-xr-x  39 coder  staff   1,3K  8 Dec 23:17 test
```

`:echo has('signs')` returns `1` as it should and I can see the differences by `git diff`

Comment: Please post an issue with the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues).

Comment: OK, I've created a ticket: https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues/216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `pathogen` wasn't activated and it didn't load `gitgutter`. I fixed it by adding the following line to `~/.vimrc`

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```